# Why doesn't "locate" work?

Tags: unix

I tried "locate libevent", but it doesn't work. and nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have to run `updatedb` first, though it's often set up to run automatically.

Are you certain that path exists which includes libevent?  If not try searching for something you know exists (etc, your home directory, and so on)

Comment: Also if the file has been recently installed (today) there's a very good chance you need to run updatedb.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, `locate` uses a proprietary database which contains all filenames of the system (or at least of the directories which have been configured to be included in this database). To (re-) build this database you need to run `updatedb`.

You could also use *find* (e. g. `find / -name 'libevent*'`) to search for the file which will take longer (depending on the size of your harddisk) but needs no database.

Answer (score 0):

`locate` silently returns nothing when it doesn't find what you requested.